# How to push in array of object with key?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
public items: any[] = [];
```

What im trying to do :

```
this.events.map((event) => {
        this.items[event.item] = event; 
    });
```

But i always get one item for every key. Any suggestion how can i push it in this items?

In event i get this:

```
    {item: "9000225-01/17", type: "ORDER", status: "0", trackingId: 6033, statusName: "U pripremi", …} 
   {item: "9000225-01/17", type: "ORDER", status: "1", trackingId: 6035, statusName: "Primljena", …} 
    {item: "9000225-01/17", type: "ORDER", status: "8", trackingId: 6036, statusName: "TM ne postoji", …} 
  {item: "9000225-01/17-01", type: "ORDITEM", status: "0", trackingId: 6034, statusName: "U pripremi", …}
```

And now what i want is insert in `items[event.item]` all of object that have same `item` from this object above.

Comment: Have you tried with `.push()`?

Comment: i get undefined this.items[event.item] but when i console log event.item and this.items a i get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .push

```typescript
this.events.map(event => {
  if (this.items[event.item]) {
    this.items[event.item].push(event); 
  } else {
    this.items[event.item] = [event];
  }
});
```

Comment: when i do that items is empty at the end it not enter in this if statement

Comment: then what you arae expecting? i

Comment: I post my object what event return. I want in items to insert based by event.item so in my this.items i will have : [9000225-01/17] and there i will have three object and  [9000225-01/17-01]  i will have one object

Comment: its close what i need...just i need that array of that objects have key name and not 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

```
this.items[event.item].push(event);
```

Comment: i get undefined this.items[event.item]

Comment: this.items[event.item] = []; this.items[event.item].push(); This is very basic javascript

Comment: i dont see event.item its in this.events.map